# What is the difference if I combine not dead in browserlist?

Tags: javascript, gulp, package

This is my **.browserlistsrc**

```
last 2 versions
iOS 8
```

What is the difference if I combine **not dead** with these lists?

```
last 2 versions
not dead
iOS 8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of this writing the following configuration:

```
last 2 versions
iOS 8
```

Supports the following browsers:

```
and_chr 78
and_ff 68
and_qq 1.2
and_uc 12.12
android 76
baidu 7.12
bb 10
bb 7
chrome 78
chrome 77
edge 18
edge 17
firefox 70
firefox 69
ie 11
ie 10
ie_mob 11
ie_mob 10
ios_saf 13.2
ios_saf 13.0-13.1
ios_saf 8
kaios 2.5
op_mini all
op_mob 46
op_mob 12.1
opera 64
opera 63
safari 13
safari 12.1
samsung 10.1
samsung 9.2
```

The following configuratio:

```
last 2 versions
not dead
iOS 8
```

Supports browsers:

```
and_chr 78
and_ff 68
and_qq 1.2
and_uc 12.12
android 76
baidu 7.12
chrome 78
chrome 77
edge 18
edge 17
firefox 70
firefox 69
ie 11
ie_mob 11
ios_saf 13.2
ios_saf 13.0-13.1
ios_saf 8
kaios 2.5
op_mini all
op_mob 46
opera 64
opera 63
safari 13
safari 12.1
samsung 10.1
samsung 9.2
```

The difference being the following browsers which are effectively the "dead" browsers:

```
bb 10
bb 7
ie 10
ie_mob 10
op_mob 12.1
```

You can check this by executing `npx browserslist` to debug the list that a given configuration will support.